# Freely Available Real Public Data

Tags: hadoop, machine-learning, bigdata, business-intelligence, information-extraction

**Note: I am not looking for Sample Data.**

What Real Data sets are exposed for Free To Public in different domains:

For example :

1. **Financial Reports for FCM.** 
   http://www.cftc.gov/MarketReports/FinancialDataforFCMs/HistoricalFCMReports/index.htm
2. **YouTube Data:**  (Popularity Metrics and Stats of Channels)
   https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/

Please share if anymore of such data is available.

May be related to below or anything else which may be useful.

May be in Medical Domain, Pharmacy, Medicine Consumed.

Traffics, Accidents, Casualties in different Cities, Roads etc.

Women safety Metrics in different Localities.

Food/Beverages Consumption , price.

Amount of Garbage collection, Restrooms according to localities/apt.

How many Orphanage and How much funding they received.

How many Handicapped Parking available in a city etc.

***I would highly appreciate to suggest me a better forum,
if you think its not proper question for this type of platform.***

Comment: [Open Data](http://opendata.stackexchange.com) is probably the right place to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, This is right forum, there are many places data sets are available for free, I collected following links over the periods, many of them for learning purpose, there are few for real serious for problem solving.

UCI have famous data repository at http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/

Very good weather data at for at http://www.knmi.nl/climatology/daily_data/download.html

Data set for different ML problems order in terms of complexity http://college.cengage.com/mathematics/brase/understandable_statistics/7e/students/datasets/slr/frames/frame.html

If you have Wolfarm Alpha pro account, you can download research data in CSV format. For example (Hover your mouse on the plots to get download link)
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=home+prices+folsom+california
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=historical+gold+prices

As previously mentioned, past and current competitions are great source data sets to experiment and validate algorithms accuracy.
https://www.kaggle.com/competitions

There are many data sets including retail market and traffic at
http://fimi.ua.ac.be/data/

UCI Data Archive at
http://kdd.ics.uci.edu/

Statlib data arcihive
http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/datasets/

Economic Time series data sets from university of Maryland
http://inforumweb.umd.edu/econdata/econdata.html

There are many time series covering various aspect data library compiled for Monash University, Australia here (Interesting data sets about loans, Sheep population etc)
http://datamarket.com/data/list/?q=provider:tsdl

Data is considered as commodity and few sites sells data for researchers.
http://datamarket.com

Various data sets shared for learning community can be found here,
[http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/time_series_data/](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/%7Eeamonn/time_series_data/)

Collection of spatial data list at
http://geodacenter.asu.edu/datalist/

Some interesting data sets for learning
http://calcnet.mth.cmich.edu/org/spss/Prjs_DataSets.htm

British Election study data set
http://www.britishelectionstudy.com/data/#.U9M1CvmSzoE

German social survey data
http://www.gesis.org/en/allbus/allbus-home/

Research datasets from Harvard
http://www.cid.harvard.edu/ciddata/ciddata.html

Various datasets compiled on International Economics, which may require some data massaging as like many data sets found here
http://graduateinstitute.ch/home/study/academicdepartments/international-economics/md4stata/datasets.html

Community stackoverflow data in huge file can be found here for any data research
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/

Free economics, demographics and financial data (require log in)
https://www.economy.com/freelunch/

US govt data dedicated site
https://www.data.gov/

Amazon host huge public data sets on AWS
https://aws.amazon.com/datasets?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1

Collection of many datasets compiled at
http://www.kdnuggets.com/2011/02/free-public-datasets.html
http://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/big-data-sets-available-for-free
http://www.infochimps.com/datasets
http://www.quora.com/Where-can-I-find-large-datasets-open-to-the-public

XML data source
http://usgovxml.com/

Sorry for long and overwhelming data set links :)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some off the top of my head.

Amazon Web Services available public data sets:

https://aws.amazon.com/datasets

Socrata is startup software platform for cities to publish their data:

https://opendata.socrata.com/

Among the cities that use Socrata are San Francisco and New York City:

https://data.sfgov.org/

https://nycopendata.socrata.com/

UC Irvine data sets (very tiny data):

http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/

Kaggle competitions for applying machine learning to real (but anonymized) data:

https://www.kaggle.com/competitions

KDNuggets compendium of known data sets:

http://www.kdnuggets.com/datasets/index.html